# fill in a column only if its not none or empty

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to fill in the missing values of county column based on its add_suburb value. I tried the following two codes which doesn't work

```
for index, row in fileco.iterrows():
        df.loc[df['add_suburb'].str.contains(str(row['place'])) & ( df['county'].str=='') , 'county'] = str('County '+row['county']).title()


for index, row in fileco.iterrows():
        df.loc[df['add_suburb'].str.contains(str(row['place'])) & ( df['county'].str is None) , 'county'] = str('County '+row['county']).title()
```

But the following code works if i do not check for None or ==''.

```
for index, row in fileco.iterrows():
            df.loc[df['add_suburb'].str.contains(str(row['place']))  , 'county'] = str('County '+row['county']).title()
```

What's the correct way to fill in only the missing column values? How should I correct the condition after the & ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do in the loop (what are you looping over?), but I think it should work if you enclose your conditions in brackets like this:

```
df.loc[(condition1) & (condition2)] = "replacement"
```